# How to search through one list to add in elements in the same spaces of another list? Python

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I have list a, which contains characters, and List B, which contains the same amount of "_" in the list as characters in List A. As an example:

a = ["c", "a", "t"]

b = ["_", "__", "_"]

I need to write a program that searches List A for a user input, and if found in List A, will replace all of the blank spaces in List B with the character from List A.

If it helps, this is for a Hangman-like program using lists.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like this, this way accounts for multiple occurrences of the same letter:

```
a = ["c", "a", "t", "a"]
b = ["_", "_", "_", "_"]
choice = input('Pick a letter: ') #assume 'a' is picked
indices = [i for i,letter in enumerate(a) if letter == choice]
for i in indices:
    b[i] = choice
```

output:

```
['_', 'a', '_', 'a']
```